# Creating a switch-case iterating a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a HashMap made ​​in this way:

```
HashMap<M, Integer> t;
```

Where M is a class like this:

```
public class M {
    int s;
    char c;
}
```

So it's like I have a table like this:

```
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   s   |   c   |   Integer     |
+-------+-------+---------------+
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   0   |   0   |       1       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   0   |   1   |       0       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   0   |   3   |       5       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   1   |   0   |       2       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   1   |   1   |       0       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   2   |   0   |       3       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   2   |   1   |       0       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   3   |   0   |       3       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
|   3   |   1   |       3       |
+-------+-------+---------------+
```

The values ​​in the table are random.

What I would like is to create a string made ​​in this way:

```
case 0:
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 1;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 0; 
    if(ch == '3')
        st = 5;             
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
case 1:
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 2;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 0; 
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
case 2:
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 3;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 0; 
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
case 3:
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 3;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 3; 
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
```

Explain:

- The number of `case` is the number of s different between them
- In any `case` there is a `if`. The condition is dependent on the column `c` and the body depends on `Integer` column

So in practice:

Case (column "s"), if (column "c"), body (column "Integer").

I wrote this code that works pretty:

```
String g  = new String("");

for(int i = 0; i < numberOfSt(); i++) {
    g = g + "\t\t\t\tcase " + i + ": \n";
    int j = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<Move, Integer> entry : t.entrySet()) {
        Move key = entry.getKey();
        Integer value = entry.getValue();
        if(key.s == j) {
            g = g + "\t\t\t\t\tif(ch == '" + key.c + "')\n";
            g = g + "\t\t\t\t\t\tstate = " + value + ";\n";
        }
        j++;
    }
    g = g + "\t\t\t\t\telse\n";
    g = g + "\t\t\t\t\t\tstate = -1;\n";
    g = g + "\t\t\t\t\tbreak;\n";
}
```

The problem is that it creates this wrong code:

```
case 0: 
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 1;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 0;
    if(ch == '3')
        st = 0;
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
case 1: 
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 1;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 0;
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
case 2: 
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 1;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 0;
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
case 3: 
    if(ch == '0')
        st = 1;
    if(ch == '1')
        st = 0;
    else
        st = -1;
    break;
```

The "st =" are wrong ..

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

(I hope I explained myself, otherwise I will add the details you ask me..)

Comment: If `st` is wrong ... what does it contain? And what should it contain? Only the content of the column `Integer` of your example? Btw: you're using severals `if` blocks and one `else` block at the end. The means the `else` block belongs to the last `if` block. To "connect" each `if` block, use `else if`. (`if` -> `else if` -> `else if` -> ... -> `else`)

Comment: For example `case 1: if(ch == '0') st = 1`, but it sholud be `case 1: if(ch == '0') st = 2` (As noted in the table)..

Comment: Well either this is not the correct code or your result does not come from this code. I've thought that this `if(key.s == j)` condition will only be entered once and my test proved that. So there will only be one `if` block in each case and a directly following `else` block. Please check your posted code and result.